# Meaning of mathematical notation

Tags: notation

I am reading a research paper and came across following expression

$ y = (2[[c[k] = c_{min}]] - 1)$

Here $c$ is a cost function. Can someone explain how to interpret this expression.

I believe $[[]]$ is a floor function. But what does $=$ mean here. Does it compares $c[k]$ with $c_{min}$. If so then outcome of comparison is binary 0/1 and 2 times that is always an integer and so no need for floor function.

Thanks

Gerry

Comment: I know it is just a simple notational thing but I am new to it. Anybody?

Comment: It doesn't look like standard notation. Are you sure the paper doesn't define what it means with it somewhere? It it doesn't, at least tell us what the paper is _about_ (and link to it if you can!) such that readers here have a fighting chance to know which area of mathematics they should look for a meaning for this in.

Comment: Thanks for your response Henning Makholm. The link to paper is http://icml2010.haifa.il.ibm.com/papers/207.pdf and It is last line of page 3.

Comment: Iverson bracket: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

Comment: got it. Thanks @Did.

Answer (score 3):

The paper explains the notation in the footnote on page 2: It uses hollow square brackets $[\![\cdots]\!]$ as a notation for the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), which by definition means "$1$ if the claim inside the bracket is true; $0$ if it is false".

Thus, $y=2[\![c_k=c_{\rm min}]\!]-1$ is just a terse way to write
$$ y = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }c_k=c_{\rm min} \\ -1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Thanks for your help Henning.